# A density result for biharmonic functions

Tags: elliptic-pde

Let $U_1, U_2\subset\mathbb R^3$ open and homeomorphic to the open unit ball, with sufficiently smooth boundary, such that $\overline{U}_1\subset U_2$.

Is is true that every biharmonic function $u$ in $U_1$ (i.e., $\Delta^2 u=0$), which extends continuously to $\overline{U}_1$, can be approximated by linear combinations of the form
$$
c_0+\sum_{j=1}^n c_j |x-x_j|,
$$
where $n\in\mathbb N$, $c_j\in\mathbb R$, and $x_j\in\partial U_2$. In particular, I am interested in approximation with respect to the norms of the spaces $C^\ell\big(\overline{U}_1\big)$.

Note that $\varphi(x)=-\frac{1}{8\pi}|x|$ is biharmonic function in $\mathbb R^3\smallsetminus\{0\}$ and a fundamental solution of $\Delta^2$, i.e., $\Delta^2\varphi=\delta$, in the sense of distributions.

NOTE. There is a correction: $c_0$ is added in the linear combination.

Comment: The answer is "No" even for 2 balls. The easiest way to see it is to notice that both the value at the center and the integral over a sphere allow one to recover $\sum c_j$ but they are not related. The underlying reason is obvious: it is pretty hard to recover the normal derivative by the boundary difference quotients, which go tangentially.

Comment: See NOTE in the edited version.